# UK visa IHS payment

Tags: uk-visa

I'm traveling to the UK from the US to work.  I already have my visa.  I'm filling out visa applications for my kids.  During the visa application process you have to prepay the Immigration Health Surcharge.  The IHS payment is based on how long your visa is.  I had a massive brain fart and instead of entering when my visa expires (2020) I entered when my visa entry expires (next week).  So the site charged me nothing for my kids' IHS.

The UK visa site will not let you go back and fix this.  I've already paid for the visa applications and set up their biometric collection appointments.

Is this going to negatively affect their visa applications?  Is there a way to fix this short of canceling the applications, requesting a refund, and redoing them from scratch?  Can I pay via [this site](https://www.immigration-health-surcharge.service.gov.uk/ego/#/register) once they get to the UK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called the UKVI helpline and it was explained to me that one of two things would happen if I went ahead with the applications:

1. The applications would be rejected outright.
2. UKVI would call me and attempt to get my payment over the phone but that's sometimes difficult.

It was advised that I cancel the applications, request a refund on the fees, and redo them correctly.  That's what I did.